# If f has a 4-periodic point $x_1$ st, $x_1<f(x_1)<f^2(x_1)<f^3(x_1)$ show $f$ has a periodic point of any order.

Tags: dynamical-systems

Suppose $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ has a periodic orbit ${x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < x_4}$
such that $f(x_i)= x_{i+1}$ for $i < 4$ and $f(x_4) = x_1$. Show that $f$ has periodic
points of all periods.

This problem is in a chapter about Sharkovsky Theorem, thus I think I have to use it. I somehow need to show that $f$ has a point of period 3, and then we are done by Sharkovsky. However, how do we show it has a point of period 3?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $T$ has an orbit of period 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249182/prove-that-t-has-an-orbit-of-period-3). See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3841445 for a similar question about a 5-cycle with a diagram of the relevant graph.